# How to calculate a lattice constant from scattering electrons?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, scattering, intensity, braggs-law

[image]

Does someone know how to solve that problem? Is it using Bragg's law? I know that in Bragg's law, the incident angle and reflection angle are the same but in the picture it is not.

Problem:

When electron beams accelerated through $60$ V potential are incident on a
hypothetical 2-d rectangular crystal as in the below, the scattered electrons show a
strong intensity at $\phi = 60^o$. What is $a$?